# Render metadata for pagination from Grails RestfulController index/search actions

Tags: json, rest, grails, pagination, metadata

I am looking for  best practices / solution to  make 'respond' method generate extra metadata in the resulting json along with the collection of entities got from DB.

Basically I wanted to implement pagination using that metadata in my frontend single-page-application (SPA) built with angularJS and Restangular plugin.

> PS: angularJS's $resource or Restangular expect collection results as
>   JS array.

Standard Grails `JsonCollectionRenderer/JsonRenderer` ignores the metadata supplied to 'respond' in the  map argument.

I came across following article which is implementing custom JsonRenderer, but I looking for simpler/flexible solution to make 'respond' output metadata via tweaking  custom `JsonCollectionRenderer` in `resources.groovy`

http://groovyc.net/non-trivial-restful-apis-in-grails-part-2/

My RestfulController:

```
@Secured(value=["hasRole('ROLE_USER')"])
class DrugController extends RestfulController<Drug> {

static scaffold = true
static responseFormats = ['html', 'json', 'xml', 'hal']
static allowedMethods = [show: "GET"]

DrugController() {
    super(Drug, true)
}

@Override
def index(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    // We pass which fields to be rendered with the includes attributes,
    // we exclude the class property for all responses. ***when includes are defined excludes are ignored.
    //params.fetch = [recordTypeRs:"eager"] from params.fields???
    respond resource.list(params),
            [includes: includeFields, excludes: ['class', 'errors', 'version'],
             metadata: [total: countResources(), psize: params.max, offset: params.offset?:0],
             model: [("${resourceName}InstanceCount".toString()): countResources()]]
}

@Override
def show(Drug drug) {
    JSON.use("deep") {
        respond drug,
                [includes: includeFields, excludes: ['class', 'errors', 'version']]
    }
}

private getIncludeFields() {
    params.fields?.tokenize(',')
}

def search(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    def c = Drug.createCriteria()
    def results = c.list(params) {
        //Your criteria here with params.q
        and {
            like('ndc', params.ndc?params.ndc+'%':'%')
            like('recordTypeJ.j017', params.labelerName?'%'+params.labelerName+'%':'%')
            like('recordTypeE.e017', params.productName?'%'+params.productName+'%':'%')
        }
        //cache(true)
    }
    log.debug(results.totalCount)
    respond results, model:[drugCount: results.totalCount]
}
```

}

I have following in my resources.groovy.

```
// register Renderers/CollectionRenderers for all domain classes in the application.
for (domainClass in grailsApplication.domainClasses) {
    "json${domainClass.shortName}CollectionRenderer"(JsonCollectionRenderer, domainClass.clazz)
    "json${domainClass.shortName}Renderer"(JsonRenderer, domainClass.clazz)
    "hal${domainClass.shortName}CollectionRenderer"(HalJsonCollectionRenderer, domainClass.clazz)
    "hal${domainClass.shortName}Renderer"(HalJsonRenderer, domainClass.clazz)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on ideas from

http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2013/12/grails-goodness-rendering-partial.html

http://groovyc.net/non-trivial-restful-apis-in-grails-part-2/

1. Creat a custom CollectionRenderer  e.g.,
   SumoJsonCollectionRenderer.groovy

---

```
import grails.converters.JSON
import grails.rest.render.RenderContext

import grails.rest.render.json.JsonCollectionRenderer
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mime.MimeType

import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import static groovy.transform.TypeCheckingMode.SKIP

@CompileStatic
class SumoJsonCollectionRenderer extends JsonCollectionRenderer{

    SumoJsonCollectionRenderer(Class componentType) {
        super(componentType)
    }

    public SumoJsonCollectionRenderer(Class componentType, MimeType... mimeTypes) {
        super(componentType, mimeTypes)
    }

    @CompileStatic(SKIP)
    @Override
    protected void renderJson(object, RenderContext context) {
        log.debug(object)
        log.debug(object.size())
        log.debug(object.getTotalCount())
        Map tObject = ['results':object]
        if(context.arguments?.metadata) {
            tObject['metadata'] = context.arguments.metadata
        }
        super.renderJson(tObject,context)
    }
}
```

register custom CollectionRenderer at resource.groovy

---

```
for (domainClass in grailsApplication.domainClasses) {
    "json${domainClass.shortName}CollectionRenderer"(SumoJsonCollectionRenderer, domainClass.clazz)
    "json${domainClass.shortName}Renderer"(JsonRenderer, domainClass.clazz)
    "hal${domainClass.shortName}CollectionRenderer"(HalJsonCollectionRenderer, domainClass.clazz)
    "hal${domainClass.shortName}Renderer"(HalJsonRenderer, domainClass.clazz)
}
```

Request/Response

---

http://api.mydomain.com:8080/ApiApp/drugs.json?max=5&fields=ndc,id

```
{"results":[{"id":1,"ndc":"000020803031"},{"id":2,"ndc":"000021200011"},{"id":3,"ndc":"000021407011"},{"id":4,"ndc":"000021975901"},{"id":5,"ndc":"000023004751"}],"metadata":{"total":851,"psize":5,"offset":0}}
```