# Configure HAL JSON renderer for Grails 2.4.X

Tags: json, grails, hateoas

I am starting with HAL Json on Grails 2.4.X.

I saw i have to include to bean definition in spring resources for each domain entity like:

```
halClientRenderer(HalJsonRenderer, Client)
halClientCollectionRenderer(HalJsonCollectionRenderer, Client)
```

I may want to avoid this since i will end up with huge buggy resources file ... is it possible to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general this is the correct way to handle registering custom renders. It may seem prone to issues and results in a large `Resources.groovy` file, but if you have a large number of them you may want to consider creating something to manage them, such as using a factory bean/pattern.

This [blog post](http://compiledammit.com/2012/08/16/custom-json-marshalling-in-grails-done-right/), may give you some additional ideas since it demonstrates using a single class to collect the individual renders and provides a single point to execute registering them from your Spring context.

Answer (score 2):

Ive seen that it is possible to use some code to automatically register those renderers:

```
// register Renderers/CollectionRenderers for all domain classes in the application.
for (domainClass in grailsApplication.domainClasses) {
    "json${domainClass.shortName}CollectionRenderer"(JsonCollectionRenderer, domainClass.clazz)
    "json${domainClass.shortName}Renderer"(JsonRenderer, domainClass.clazz)
    "hal${domainClass.shortName}CollectionRenderer"(HalJsonCollectionRenderer, domainClass.clazz)
    "hal${domainClass.shortName}Renderer"(HalJsonRenderer, domainClass.clazz)
}
```

Seen at [Render metadata for pagination from Grails RestfulController index/search actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23940641/render-metadata-for-pagination-from-grails-restfulcontroller-index-search-action)